# Substraction of values not showing negative

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
const my_transactions = [{amount: -100,currency: 'EUR'},{amount: -200,currency: 'EUR'},{amount: -400,currency: 'EUR'}];
let total = 0;
my_transactions.forEach(el => total = total - el.amount);
console.log('total:',total);
```

All the amounts are negative. I need to sum all the amounts and print out the balance.
As you can see, the balance is negative. It should print

```
-700
```

But the variable "total" gets a positive value. Why?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic as this is basic arithmetic and not coding related. See: [Subtraction of a negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851987/subtraction-of-a-negative-number). (You also point out your own problem in your question *'I need to **sum** all the amounts...'*)

Comment: so what does this result in? `-100 - -200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sum, not substractions

```js
const my_transactions = 
  [{amount: -100,currency: 'EUR'},
   {amount: -200,currency: 'EUR'},
   {amount: -400,currency: 'EUR'}];
   
let total = 0;

my_transactions.forEach(el => total += el.amount);

console.log('total:', total);
```

For shorter code:

```js
const my_transactions = 
  [ { amount: -100, currency: 'EUR' }
  , { amount: -200, currency: 'EUR' }
  , { amount: -400, currency: 'EUR' }
  ];
let total = my_transactions.reduce((s,{amount:v}) => s + v, 0);

console.log('total:', total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because subtracting a negative value is the same as adding a positive value.

These produce the same result:

```js
console.log('subtracting:', 0 - (-100));
console.log('adding:', 0 + (+100));
```

If your intent is for all of these negative numbers to add up to `-700` then add them instead of subtracting them:

```
my_transactions.forEach(el => total = total + el.amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the minus (`-`) operator to the plus (`+`).

Subtracting a negative number is the same as adding a positive number.

```js
const my_transactions = [
  { amount: -100, currency: 'EUR' },
  { amount: -200, currency: 'EUR' },
  { amount: -400, currency: 'EUR' }
];

let total = 0;
my_transactions.forEach(el => total = total + el.amount); // Change - to +

console.log('Total:', total);
```

A better approach is to reduce:

```js
const myTransactions = [
  { amount: -100, currency: 'EUR' },
  { amount: -200, currency: 'EUR' },
  { amount: -400, currency: 'EUR' }
];

let total = myTransactions.reduce((sum, { amount }) => sum + amount, 0);

console.log('Total:', total);
```